# Titanium Facebook API: Cannot post to page wall, (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, titanium, titanium-android

Starting to pull my hair out, cannot make this work.

I'm trying to post to a photo with a message to a Facebook page.

But no matter what I do, what permissions i set, the answer is always (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action.

I'm following this tutorial in terms of events: http://www.sergiy.ca/post-on-facebook-app-wall-and-fan-page-wall-as-admin/

```
var image = event.media;
var f = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory,'camera_photo.png');
f.write(image);
var blob = f.read();


fb.permissions = ['publish_actions',  'publish_stream', 'read_stream','manage_pages']; // Permissions your app needs
fb.reauthorize();

var at = 'pageToken'

var xhrN = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
xhrN.timeout = 1000000;
xhrN.onload = function(){    
Ti.API.info(this.responseText);     
var thetoken = this.responseText;
Ti.API.info('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/' + pageid + '/photos?'+ thetoken);

var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
    onload: function(e) {
        alert(e);
        Ti.API.info('Photo Saved');
        Ti.API.info(e);
    }
});


var endPoint = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/' + pageid + '/photos';
xhr.open('POST',endPoint);
xhr.send({
    message: 'This is my message',
    picture: event.media
});


    var data = {
        name : "The Name",
        message : 'The Message',
        caption : "The caption",
        access_tokxen: thetoken
    };

    /*
    fb.requestWithGraphPath('123456789/feed', data, 'POST', function(e) {
        if (e.success) {
            alert(e.result);
            Ti.API.info('App projde');
        } else if (e.error) {
            alert(e.error);
        } else {
            alert('Unknown response');
        }
    });
    */

    fb.requestWithGraphPath('123456789/feed', data, 'POST', function(e) {
        if (e.success) {
            alert(e.result);
            Ti.API.info('Wall projde');
        } else if (e.error) {
            alert(e.error);
        } else {
            alert('Unknown response');
        }
    });

// *****

};

xhrN.open('GET','https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?type=client_cred&client_id=clientid&client_secret=clientsecret');
xhrN.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set appid. Read [facebook module docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Modules.Facebook) carefully.

Comment: Sorry, those are set, i just didnt want to display them here, that's not the culprit

Comment: you set them in the tiapp?